Calculate rinverse laplace transform with essential singularity
I am trying to calculate invers Laplace transforms of a class of functions:
$\tilde{G}=\frac{1-f(s)}{s}e^{(f(s)-1)y}$ where the function $f(s)$ is a function that has simple poles and such that $f(0)=1$ because is the Laplace transform of a non-negative function that integrates to $1$ (it's a PDF).
For example, for $f(s)=\frac{1}{1+s x_1}$ I was able to get a result: $G(x,y)=e^{-y-x/x_1}I_0(2\sqrt{xy/x_1})$. This was easy when I noticed that the Laplace transforms of $I_0(2\sqrt{xy})$ was $e^{y/s}/s$, then I could get the result by just performing a few change of variables.
Now I am trying to generalise, and I wanted to find a general was to find solutions, including $f(s)=\frac{1}{(1+sx_1)(1+sx_2)}$, $f(s)=\frac{1-e^{-sx_1}}{sx_1}$ and $f(s)=e^{-sx_1}$. But these seem much harder. In general, I think I'd need to find the residues for $\tilde{G}$?
